# Don'tcha want stackexchange.music?

Tags: discussion

It appears this site has been in beta for a while.  Eventually we should get our own domain name.

.music registration appears to be *free* right now.  I don't think `sx.music` is the best name, maybe `discuss.music` or `talk.music`?

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's free for *pre-registration*, but hey, go for it!

Answer (score 4):

Most stack exchange sites **do not** get their own domain name, and on various meta.so discussions it has been made clear that there is no intention to provide domain names for each site.

It makes sense for the high traffic trilogy, but for music.se, which hasn't even graduated yet, I'd be surprised.

Comment: For $0 and with the one-word names that are available now?  How inconvenient is it to rename DNS entries (it's easy).

Comment: @bobobobo If you wanted to, you could register that domain right now and have it point to this site! StackExchange is not likely to register things outside of their domain except in extreme circumstances, as noted above.

Comment: DNS and certificates are actually a major problem for SE

Comment: Well SSL certs are expensive. But setting up the DNS is easy easy easy.

Comment: There are also issues of isolating sites on their own little domain island. Google already know that stackexchange.com represents reliable, "high quality" content wherein a custom domain loses all that Google juice. But in reality, the **highly-divisive arguments** over picking names (and BAD ones at that) were way more destructive than helpful. We're not likely to go down that road again — http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/